# Manipulate JSON data wrt index from different array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JSON data as

```
var myjson = {
            'key1' : {
                'type' : 'key1 type',
                'key1-1' : {
                    'type' : 'key1-1 type',
                    'data' : 'key1-1 value'
                },
                'key1-2' : {
                    'type' : 'key1-2 type',
                    'data' : 'key1-2 value'
                },
                'key1-3' : {
                    'type' : 'key1-3 type',
                    'key1-3-1' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-3-1 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                    },
                    'key1-3-2' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-3-2 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                    },
                    'key1-3-3': {
                        'type' : 'key1-3-3 type',
                        'key1-3-3-1' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-3-1 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-3-1 value'
                        },
                        'key1-3-3-2' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-3-2 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-3-2 value'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

and array of dynamic index:

```
var index = ['key1', 'key1-3', 'key1-3-3']
```

I need to insert data in myjson using index variable

```
myjson['key1']['key1-3']['key1-3-3']['key1-3-3-3'] = {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-3-3 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-3-3 value'
                        }
```

How can the output be achieved(either using recursion, eval, swapping or by any means) as :

```
`myjson = {
                'key1' : {
                    'type' : 'key1 type',
                    'key1-1' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-1 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-1 value'
                    },
                    'key1-2' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-2 type',
                        'data' : 'key1-2 value'
                    },
                    'key1-3' : {
                        'type' : 'key1-3 type',
                        'key1-3-1' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-1 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                        },
                        'key1-3-2' : {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-2 type',
                            'data' : 'key1-3-1 value'
                        },
                        'key1-3-3': {
                            'type' : 'key1-3-3 type',
                            'key1-3-3-1' : {
                                'type' : 'key1-3-3-1 type',
                                'data' : 'key1-3-3-1 value'
                            },
                            'key1-3-3-2' : {
                                'type' : 'key1-3-3-2 type',
                                'data' : 'key1-3-3-2 value'
                            },
                            'key1-3-3-3' : {
                                'type' : 'key1-3-3-3 type',
                                'data' : 'key1-3-3-3 value'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = index.reduce(function(obj, key){
    return obj[key];
}, myjson);

obj['key1-3-3-3'] = {
    type: 'key1-3-3-3 type',
    data: 'key1-3-3-3 value'
};
```

Documentation on `reduce` is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thank you for saving my life genius. I am wondering how could this script act like a pass by reference...

Comment: I've renamed the variable in the function passed to `reduce` from `index` to `key` because it had the same name as your `index` array. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var curlevel = myjson;
for (i = 0; i < index.length-1; i++) {
    curlevel = curlevel[index[i]];
}
curlevel[index[i]] = {
    type: newtype,
    data: newdata
};
```